# Should i choose arraylist or linked list for adding and deleting N objects at the beginning of the data structure?

Tags: data-structures, arraylist, linked-list

public  addNNodes(T dataStructure, int Nodes){
    }

```
public <T> deleteNNodes(T dataStructure, int Nodes){
}

public static void main(String args[]){
  // Which method to use to add or to delete? Should i use linked list or arraylist?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to add and remove from the beginnign of the structure you can use a Stack. Then use push to add to the beginning and pop to remove. [Java Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)

Answer (score 1):

You want a linked list, array list will be much slower for large values of N